# How to convert an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I need to reformat an array from one type to another using library "Lodash".

I initially have such an array:

```
[{
    "language": {
      "displayName": {
        "en": "English"
      },
      "id": 1
    },
    "level": {
      "id": 1,
      "displayName": {
        "en": "Intermediate"
      }
    }
  }, {
    "language": {
      "displayName": {
        "en": "Russian"
      },
      "id": 2
    },
    "level": {
      "id": 1
      "displayName": {
        "en": "Fluent"
      }
    }
  }]
```

How to convert an array in this format:

```
[{
    "language": 1, // it is language.id
    "level": 1 // it is level.id
  }, {
    "language": 2, // it is language.id
    "level": 2 // it is level.id
}]
```

Comment: could you please add the code you've tried with so far :)

Comment: This can be done in one line of vanilla javascript. Is lodash really a requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like this:

```js
const input=[{language:{displayName:{en:"English"},id:1},level:{id:1,displayName:{en:"Intermediate"}}},{language:{displayName:{en:"Russian"},id:2},level:{id:1,displayName:{en:"Fluent"}}}];

const output = input.map(o => ({ language: o.language.id, level: o.level.id }))

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). In the map call back function you can access individual object & each object will have `language` & `level` as key.Key `id` is nested inside language and level key. So to retrieve value of `id` you need `item.language.id` & `item.level.id` where item is current object

```js
let data = [{
  "language": {
    "displayName": {
      "en": "English"
    },
    "id": 1
  },
  "level": {
    "id": 1,
    "displayName": {
      "en": "Intermediate"
    }
  }
}, {
  "language": {
    "displayName": {
      "en": "Russian"
    },
    "id": 2
  },
  "level": {
    "id": 1,
    "displayName": {
      "en": "Fluent"
    }
  }
}];


let newData = data.map(function(item) {
  return {
    language: item.language.id,
    level: item.level.id
  }

});

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map()` as already shown. However, a `Lodash` solution as required will be using [_.map()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map) in combination with [_.mapValues()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mapValues)

```js
const input = [{"language":{"displayName":{"en":"English"},"id":1},"level":{"id":1,"displayName":{"en":"Intermediate"}}},{"language":{"displayName":{"en":"Russian"},"id":2},"level":{"id":2,"displayName":{"en":"Fluent"}}}];

let res = _.map(input, o => _.mapValues(o, "id"));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `map` using nested destructuring to extract the properties you want:

```js
const arr = [{"language":{"displayName":{"en":"English"},"id":1},"level":{"id":1,"displayName":{"en":"Intermediate"}}},{"language":{"displayName":{"en":"Russian"},"id":2},"level":{"id":1,"displayName":{"en":"Fluent"}}}];
const res = arr.map(({ language: { id: language }, level: { id: level }}) => ({ language, level }));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Here's a Lodash version using [`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map) and [`_.mapValues`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mapValues) (to avoid `_.map` of [`_.values`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#values) which is more verbose):

```js
const arr = [{"language":{"displayName":{"en":"English"},"id":1},"level":{"id":1,"displayName":{"en":"Intermediate"}}},{"language":{"displayName":{"en":"Russian"},"id":2},"level":{"id":1,"displayName":{"en":"Fluent"}}}];
const res = _.map(arr, e => _.mapValues(e, ({ id }) => id));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```